# Dynamically filling a table based off of what is selected in a dropdown menu in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, datatable, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a table with 4 possible set of variables. I also have a dropdown (select) menu.

I want to:

Fill out the table in way #1 when the first option in dropdown  is selected.

Fill out the table in way #2 when the second option in dropdown is selected.

Fill out the table in way #3 when the third option in dropdown  is selected.

Fill out the table in way #4 when the fourth option in dropdown  is selected.

**UPDATE:**
I changed "@click" to "@change" now it only seems to pass the first option as the value no matter which option I choose!

I have written a code that should do it but it doesn't:

```
<template>
<div>

 <v-card class="table1">
   <v-card-title>
    <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
      <v-select
        :mandatory="false"
        :items=dropItems
        label="dropSelect"
        v-model="dropSelect"
        @change="hasan">
      </v-select>
    </v-flex>
  </v-card-title>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="componentItems"
    hide-actions
    class="elevation-20"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>
        <!--some rows-->
      </td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-card>
</div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
    data() {
      return {
       dropItems: ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4'],
       dropSelect: null,
       componentItems:[],
       headers: ['header values']}
  },
methods: {
  hasan() {
    if (this.dropSelect = 'option1') {
      this.componentItems = ['valeus version 1'];
    }
    else if (this.dropSelect ='option2') {
      this.componentItems = ['values version 2'];
    }
    else if (this.dropSelect = 'option3') {
      this.componentItems = ['values version 3'];
    }
    else if (this.dropSelect = 'option4') {
      this.componentItems = ['values version 4'];
    }
   }
 }
}
```

I think the problem is when componentItems is set to let's say 'option1' it doesn't update it on the

```
<v-data-table
.
.
:items="componentItems"
.
.
>
```

am I correct? If yes then how do I simultaneously update the table?
If not what's the best way to update the table based off of the value selected from the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to change:
    this.dropSelect = 'option1'
to
    this.dropSelect === 'option1'

adding two more equal signs.